# Creating a DropDownListFor in loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create several drop-down lists on the form, but the selected item is not displayed in each list. Model:

```cs
 public class CreditOrganizationCurrencyModel
    {
        public List<CreditOrganizationCurrencyPair> CurrencyPairs { get; set; }    
    }

    public class CreditOrganizationCurrencyPair
    {
        public string SelectedCurrencyId1 { get; set; }
        public string SelectedCurrencyId2 { get; set; }
        public CreditOrganizationCurrency CurrencyPair { get; set; }
    }
```

Data generation:

```cs
List<CreditOrganizationCurrency> currencyCouples = CreditOrganizationHelper.Instance.GetOrganizationCurrencyCouples(id).ToList();

            var pairs = new List<CreditOrganizationCurrencyPair>();
            foreach (var currency_pair in currencyCouples)
            {
                pairs.Add(new CreditOrganizationCurrencyPair() 
                {
                    CurrencyPair = currency_pair,
                    SelectedCurrencyId1 = currency_pair.Currency1.Id.ToString(),
                    SelectedCurrencyId2 = currency_pair.Currency2.Id.ToString()
                });
            }
```

List for each DropDownListFor:

```cs
List<SelectListItem> currencies = CurrencyHelper.Instance.GetAll()
                    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString()})
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Text)
                    .ToList();
```

View:

```cs
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.CurrencyPairs.Count; i++)
{ 
%>                    
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrencyPairs[i].SelectedCurrencyId1) %>
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrencyPairs[i].SelectedCurrencyId1, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Currencies"])%>
<%} %>
```

At the same time, if you use a separate field with an ID, then the selected element works successfully (TestId is specified in controller):

```cs
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TestID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Currencies"])%>
```

The feeling that the problem is that the desired ID for the drop-down list is nested in another structure, but I can't explain it

Comment: Still acutally.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    <% if (Model.CurrencyPairs != null) 
    { %>
        <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.CurrencyPairs.Count; i++)
        {%>
            $("#CurrencyPairs_<%: i %>__FirstCurrency_Id").val("<%:Model.CurrencyPairs[i].FirstCurrency.Id %>");
            $("#CurrencyPairs_<%: i %>__SecondCurrency_Id").val("<%:Model.CurrencyPairs[i].SecondCurrency.Id %>");
     <% } %>
 <% } %>
});
```

The problem was solved using js: after loading the page, go through the displayed list and and set the selected item. But this is a crutch, I have not found another solution...